# How to apply multiple filter to the particular Portion of video

Tags: ios, swift, video, filter, gpuimage

I want to apply filter to the video like **tiktok** **app**. for example If my video is 1 min long then I want to apply one filter till 30 second and another filter till 30 sec so I need two filter effects for 1min long video.

Using following Code I have applied one static filter effect to whole video via GPUImage

```
import UIKit
import GPUImage

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var renderView: RenderView!

    var movie:MovieInput!
    var filter:SketchFilter!

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        let bundleURL = Bundle.main.resourceURL!
        let movieURL = URL(string:"Jelly.3gp", relativeTo:bundleURL)!

        do {
            movie = try MovieInput(url:movieURL, playAtActualSpeed:true)
            filter = SketchFilter()
            movie --> filter --> renderView
            movie.runBenchmark = true
            movie.start()
        } catch {
            print("Couldn't process movie with error: \(error)")
        }

     }
 }
```

How can I get video Range or anything which help me to achieve this?

Comment: Are you able to find any solution for this?